# Python 3 Exception: TypeError: function missing 1 required positional argument: 'words'

Tags: python, function, exception, arguments, try-catch

My function needs one argument words, but i want the program not to crash if no argument.

```
def get_count(words):
    try:
        consonants_str = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
        vowels_str = "aeiouAEIOU"
        consonants_ls = []
        vowels_ls = []
        words_ls = []
        result = {"vowels": 0, "consonants": 0}`

        for element in consonants_str:
            consonants_ls.append(element)

        for element in vowels_str:
            vowels_ls.append(element)

        if type(words) != type(None):
            for element in words:
                words_ls.append(element)

            for element in words_ls:
                if element in vowels_ls:
                    result["vowels"] += 1
                if element in consonants_ls:
                    result["consonants"] += 1
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                result["vowels"] = 0
                result["consonants"] = 0

    except TypeError:
        result["vowels"] = 0
        result["consonants"] = 0

    answer = {"vowels": result["vowels"],"consonants": result["consonants"]}

    return answer`
```

So if I execute the function with

```
print(get_count())
```

I want, that the program doesn't show me an error like the one in the heading. The exception for that should be in the `def` of `get_count` because it should be a closed file. I don't execute in the same file, so the Exception should be independent from other files.

I hope you understand what I mean...

Thanks for your answers!
NoAbL

Comment: It works now. I'm sorry that i can't give the green hook to 2 people, so i gave it to the one who answered first and helped me a lot. That doesn't mean the other answers are less good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing an argument to your function, when you declared that you want an argument named `words` with `def(words)`, call your function like this or with any string input you desire

```
print(get_count('AAAABBBKDKDKDKDA'))
```

if you want the program to exit when no argument is passed, do this (remember words is now a tuple)

```
import sys

def get_count(*words):
    if not words: # if words is empty, no argument was passed
        sys.exit('You passed in no arguments')
    else:
        pass # do something with the items in words
```

Comment: I know, i want an escape sequence or something like that if i don't pass an argument.

Comment: use `def get_count(*args)` args is a tuple and enables you to pass no argument at all or pass in any number of non-named arguments

Comment: you can use any name like `*optional` but `*args` is what is used by the community,  personally i've never seen any standard code that uses a different name. but it's important that you know about the freedom that python allows in that area

Comment: If i change the `def get_count(words)` to `def get_count(*words)`, the output is always `{"consonants": 0, "vowels": 0}`

Comment: because words is no longer a string it's now a tuple containing strings, so it should be `for element in words[0]` that's if you care about only the first string passed (multiple strings can be passed in to the function)

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way:

```
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> def get_count(words):
...     words = words.lower()
...     total_vowels = sum(words.count(x) for x in vowels)
...     return {'vowels':total_vowels, 'consonants':len(words)-total_vowels}
... 
>>> get_count('AAAABBBKDKDKDKDA')
{'consonants': 11, 'vowels': 5}
```

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> def get_count(words):
...     words = words.lower()
...     my_counter = collections.Counter(words)
...     total_vowels = sum(my_counter.get(x,0) for x in 'aeiou')
...     return {'vowels':total_vowels, 'consonants':len(words)-total_vowels}
... 
>>> get_count('AAAABBBKDKDKDKDA')
{'consonants': 11, 'vowels': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Optional parameters**

For example:

```
def info(name, age=10):
```

is a function with optional parameter `age`.

The valid calls of info are:

```
info("Roy")
info("Roy", 15)
```

In your case you can just change your function to this:

```
def get_count(words=[]): # Assuming words is a list. If it is a string you can use words=""
```

So, if you don't pass any arguments, by default the function takes `words` as an empty `list`.

**Bonus:**

I've found

```
for element in consonants_str:
    consonants_ls.append(element)

for element in vowels_str:
    vowels_ls.append(element)
```

You don't need this. Instead you can do this:

```
consonants_ls = list(consonants_str)
vowels_ls = list(vowels_str)
```