# calling functions python from outside

Tags: python, function

I have small a python script looking something like this:

```
def number1():
    x = 1
    open_numbers = []
    open_numbers.append(x)
    return open_numbers

def myfunction(open_numbers):
    y = 1
    open_numbers.append(y)
```

I would like to call the myfunction in the the end of the script. Using

```
myfunction()
```

But it keeps telling me `missing 1 required positional argument: 'open_numbers'`

Tried passing the argument and got `name 'open_numbers' is not defined`

I plan to add more functions later and run them the same way

```
function(arg)
function2(arg)
function3(arg)
```

Comment: What data are you trying to give to `myfunction`? `open_numbers` only exists inside of `number1`. You need to use the return from that function if you want to use it.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. - [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: The list open_numbers[]

Comment: if you call the function `myfunction()` without any arguments, you'll get the first error: `1 required positional argument: 'open_numbers'`.



If you call it with the argument `open_numbers`, you need to define `open_numbers` out of the scope of the function or define it as a new local variable inside the function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 Exception: TypeError: function missing 1 required positional argument: 'words'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968844/python-3-exception-typeerror-function-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but in the future you really need to make a [mre] including how you're calling `myfunction` with `open_numbers`, and the full error message with traceback. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: I fixed the indenting cause it seems like your source code is fine, you just made a typo while writing the question. Otherwise you would have gotten an `IndentationError`

Comment: You might want to read about [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125172/4518341) and [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

First of all, your code was not properly indented. I have corrected that.
The function `myfunction` takes in a `list` (`open_numbers`) as input and should return it as well.

I have passed in the output of `number1()` as the input to `myfunction()`. This should create a list: `[1, 1]`. And that's what it did.

```py
def number1():
    x = 1
    open_numbers = []
    open_numbers.append(x)
    return open_numbers


def myfunction(open_numbers):
    y = 1
    open_numbers.append(y)
    return open_numbers

myfunction(number1())
```

**Output**:

```sh
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass in an object to your function. you can call your function with an empty list if you want:

```
a = []
myfunction(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define default parameter, and return the updated value

```
def myfunction(open_numbers = []):
    y = 1
    open_numbers.append(y)
    return open_numbers
```

Then you can call it with passing parameter
`myfunction([1])` or without `myfunction()`

Comment: [Using a mutable default argument is probably a bad idea](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html). For example try running `for _ in range(2): print(myfunction())`